# Outputting a Square Shape C++ using '*'

Tags: c++, output, shapes

Hello I am very new to programming and my assignment is to output shapes. The first is the square:

```
int main(){
unsigned size;
cout <<"Size: ? ";
cin >>size;
for ( unsigned r = 0; r < size; r++ ){ // Square
    for ( unsigned c = 0; c < size ; c++ )
        if ( r == c ) 
            cout <<'*';
    cout <<endl;
}
cout <<endl;
}
```

When I input "5" after being prompted. The output results in:
5

*

*

*

*

*

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code? I need to have both horizontal and vertical outputs. Thank you

Comment: You need to fill in the blanks too -- whenever you *don't* output `'*'`, you want to output `' '`, otherwise all you'll get is a collection of stars that are not aligned.

Comment: Agreed. I was use an else statement for the " ". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
unsigned size;  
bool solid = true;  //solid or hollow shape? 
cout <<"Size: ? "; 
cin >>size; 
size = 5; 
cout << endl; 

for ( unsigned r = 0; r < size; r++ ){ // Square 
    for ( unsigned c = 0; c < size ; c++ ){ 
        if(solid){ 
            cout << " * "; 
        } 
        else{ 
            if(r == 0 || r == size-1 || c == 0 or c == size-1){ 
                cout << " * "; 
            } 
            else{ 
                cout << "   "; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    cout <<endl; 
} 
cout <<endl; 
}
```

```
Output Hollow:
```

```
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *           * 
 *           * 
 *           * 
 *  *  *  *  *
```

Solid:

```
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  * 
 *  *  *  *  *
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot dude. It's been hard for me to grasp the concept with r & c, but your input helps a lot.

Comment: @BoyWonder Good to hear it helped you! Please, do not forget to mark it as Answer if you liked it.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which is, "What is wrong with my code?"

Answer (score 2):

You are only outputting a * on the diagonal, when r is the same as c. And you output nothing else but some endlines, so you end up with just a single star on each line.

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote the code to if ( r == c || r+c ) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Only time the * is printed is when r == c. What's the purpose of the if statement?
Try commenting the if statement and see the result.

Comment: Aw thanks! Yeah I don't know why I had that if statement there, was just thinking ahead for the other shapes.